# Unkown 6-sided dice. After 600 rolls frequency for all sides exactly equal. What is the chance, that rolling "6" with this dice has frequency > 1/6?

Tags: r, dirichlet-distribution, mathematica, paradox

Although it is unknown dice, the symmetry of the evidence tells us, that we can treat the dice as fair, so the chance should be exactly 50%.

But if we simulate it by hand, the result is less then 50%:

- *Mathematica code*

```
In[1]:= nsym = 200000 (*Some very large number of simulations*)
In[46]:= sample = RandomReal[DirichletDistribution[Table[100, {6}]], nsym]; 
In[51]:= counts = If[#1 > 1/6, 1, 0] & /@ #1 & /@ Transpose[sample]; 
In[52]:= N[Plus @@ Transpose[counts]/nsym] 
Out[52]= {0.49387, 0.48934, 0.487965, 0.488245, 0.49123}
```

- *R code*

```
require(gtools)
nsym=200000  #Some very large number of simulations
sample<-rdirichlet(nsym,rep(100,6))
apply(sample,2,function(x,testval){sum(x>testval)},testval=1/6)/nsym
# [1] 0.489715 0.490490 0.489800 0.490315 0.491900 0.488165
```

What am I doing wrong??

---

update:

I've found out empirically, that the mean of the difference between the above probabilities and the "expected" 0.5 equals approximately $0.096/\sqrt{100}$, where "100" is the number of prior trials.

Comment: What justifies drawing from the Dirichlet distribution to simulate outcomes of the rolls of a die?

Comment: @whuber I do Bayesian reasoning here: I don't simulate outcomes of the rolls of die - for that I'd use categorial distribution. I simulate the probabilities with which the die rolls, given the already observed historical outcomes, i.e. the posterior distribution of the parameters $\pi_{1\ldots6}$ that define the die.

Comment: Thank you.  I think it would help to edit your question to make that approach clearer, rather than relying on the code to convey what you are doing. Consider improving the title, too: because it refers to "frequency" it suggests something other than the (posterior) *probabilities* which you seem to be estimating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirichlet distribution is not multivariate normal, so it makes no sense to expect that mean ($1/6$) equals median (i.e. one observes values below mean with frequency 0.5).

The bigger is evidence (i.e. the number "100" is greater), the more the dirichlet distribution converges to normal distribution.

*Why the expected 0.5 frequency is bigger then the observed?*

It so happens, that (similar to the beta distribution) dirichlet distribution is positively skewed when the shape parameter is < 0.5 (in our case it equals 1/6). Hence the mean (0.5) is greater then the median.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like 2% of the time you probably get exactly 100 rolls which is neither greater or less than 1/6. It is exactly 1/6.